# C# MySql - data does not appear after insert new data

Tags: windows

First of all, I'm new to C# and also programming. So, my situation is after I insert data from a textbox to MySql database, the new data does not appear. FYI, I have the navigation (next previous) button. I have to re-run the apps in order for the new data to be displayed. Here's part of the codes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MySql codes to display in textbox            
        showData(pos);
    }
    public void showData(int index)
    {            
        txtDisplay.Text = table.Rows[index][0].ToString();
    }
    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
    }
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
    }
    private void btnGenNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //codes to generate new data and also insert into db            
    }        
}
```

Here's my full codes:

[image: first part]

[image: second part]

Comment: Actually I did but I can't do so because SO admin set limit for the codes :(

Comment: Please study the concept of [mcve]. That applies to you OP and also to you, @The_Black_Smurf (asking for "entire code" is unhelpful and misleads newbies).